# What's identity value of a universal function in NumPy? What is it used for?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

According to NumPy's document, `numpy.ufunc.identity` is

> Data attribute containing the identity element for the ufunc, if it
>   has one. If it does not, the attribute value is None.

I don't understand what is identity element. After reading an example from [numpy.ufunc.reduce](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) as below,

```
r = op.identity # op = ufunc
for i in range(len(A)):
  r = op(r, A[i])
return r
```

it looks like identity value *i* is just used for initialization process such that for a universal function that has two arguments *f(x, y)*, *f(i, y)=y*. What's identity value of a universal function? What is it used for?

Comment: It's the starting point for calculations like `0+a+b+c...` and `1*a*b*c...`.

Answer (score 4):

Identity is a term from [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element). The identity value of an operation is the value that makes the operation do nothing, basically. For example, the additive identity is 0, because `a + 0 = a` and `0 + a = a` for all `a`. So if you do in the interpreter:

```
>>> numpy.add.identity
0
```

There is no such number for subtraction (`2 - 0 = 0`, but `0 - 2 = -2`), so `numpy.subtract.identity` is `None`

Answer (score 2):

Try that sample code:

```
In [34]: A = np.array([1,2,3])
In [35]: op = np.add
In [36]: r = op.identity
In [37]: r
Out[37]: 0
In [38]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     r = op(r, A[i])
    ...:     
In [39]: r
Out[39]: 6
```

Now with multiplication; first with the same starting point as for add:

```
In [40]: op = np.multiply
In [41]: r = 0
In [42]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     r = op(r, A[i])
    ...:     
In [43]: r
Out[43]: 0
```

Now with the multiply identity:

```
In [44]: r = op.identity
In [45]: r
Out[45]: 1
In [46]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     r = op(r, A[i])
    ...:     
In [47]: r
Out[47]: 6
```

In other words the `identity` gives the `op.reduce` a proper starting point.